# Finding the Volume Enclosed by the Complex Plane and the Magnitude of a Complex Function

Tags: integration, complex-numbers, complex-integration

How would one find the volume of the region under the magnitude of a complex function over a given region of the complex plane? For example for the complex function: $$f(z) = z$$ for $z \in \Bbb{C} $, how to calculate the volume under $|f(z)|$ for the square region bounded by $0$ and $1$ on the real axis and bounded by $0$ and $i$ on the imaginary axis?

Comment: ${\pi \over 2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polar coordinates are well adapted to express $|f(z)|=|z|=r$ but a square has $\cos$ and $\sin$ at denominator which is not so nice to integrate.

[Converting unit square domain in (x,y) to polar coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1248630/converting-unit-square-domain-in-x-y-to-polar-coordinates)

As you can see in the answer above, it is feasible, but already complicated for even simple functions.

For $f(z)=z$ this gives $\displaystyle I=\int_0^{\frac\pi4}\int_0^{1/\cos(\theta)}r^2drd\theta+\int_{\frac\pi4}^{\frac\pi2}\int_0^{1/\sin(\theta)}r^2drd\theta$

And you can conclude with : [Integral $ \int \frac{\operatorname d\!x}{\sin^3 x} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258754/integral-int-frac-operatorname-d-x-sin3-x?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Result: $I=\frac 16(2\sqrt{2}+\operatorname{argch}(3))$

In some cases, it may be easier to keep integrating on the square domain $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ where $x(z)=\Re(f(z))$ and  $y(z)=\Im(f(z))$ as suggested by the accepted answer to the first referenced thread, but I think it all depends of what $f(z)$ looks like.

$\displaystyle I=\int_0^1\int_0^1 \sqrt{x^2+y^2}dxdy$ and I guess a change of variable like $x=y\sinh(u)$ lead to the same kind of calculation than previously.

The result $I\simeq0.7652$ is slightly greater than $\frac 18(\frac 43\pi R^3)=\frac\pi6\simeq 0.5236$ which is the volume of the first octant of the unit sphere, which is reassuring.